# Wordpress - Insert last update date in header

Tags: wordpress

I added a line in my Wordpress HTML code ( header.php ) to set the date of last update. You understand that i have to make it everytime i make a new post or put a new product. Is there a way to do it automatically? I'd like to get the date of the last post/product and echo it in the header. My knowledge of PHP is poor, sorry for that.

Comment: Do you want to display last published post date or updated post date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in `functions.php`

```
<?php
    function last_updated(){
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = "SELECT post_modified
                FROM $wpdb->posts
                WHERE post_type='post' OR post_type='product'
                AND post_status='publish'
                ORDER BY post_modified DESC
                LIMIT 1";
        $last_update = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
        $last_update = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($last_update));
        return $last_update;
    }
    add_shortcode('last_updated_date','last_updated');

?>
```

Add this code in `header.php`

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[last_updated_date]');?>
```

Comment: Wow, this is just great and fast! Maybe i can ask you how to change the date format? Big thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: How do I do the same thing for the last post published date, please.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh, Can you explain detailed?

Comment: @Vel I mean to show the product published to date(when the last time a new product was published on the website), not the modified date.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh, change this `post_modified ` to `post_date` in sql query.